# Signal update don't call effect

Tags: angular, angular-signals

Announcements value in below code changes successfully. `effect` executes once, but not when `changeDates` executes.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'platform',
})
export class AnnouncementsService {
  announcements: WritableSignal<Announcements>;
  constructor(private logger: NGXLogger) {
    this.announcements = signal({
      start: new Date('2023-08-27'),
      end: new Date('2023-09-03'),
      content: `some content`,
    });
    effect(() => {this.logger.debug('test data')})
  }

  changeDates(howMuch: number) {
    this.announcements.update((announcements: Announcements) => {
      announcements.start.setDate(announcements.start.getDate() + howMuch);
      announcements.end.setDate(announcements.end.getDate() + howMuch);
      return announcements;
    });
  }

  goForward() {
    this.changeDates(7);
  }
  goBackwards() {
    this.changeDates(-7);
  }
}
```

Is it bug? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the angular [doc](https://angular.io/guide/signals#effects):

> Effects always run at least once. When an effect runs, it tracks any
> signal value reads. Whenever any of these signal values change, the
> effect runs again.

You need to read signal inside effects so that effects runs whenever signal value changes

```
effect(() => {this.logger.debug(`test data ${this.announcements()}`)})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to return a new object ( with a new reference ). The problem is that you change in place. The solution is as simple as follows:

```
changeDates(howMuch: number) {
    this.announcements.update((announcements: Announcements) => {
      announcements.start.setDate(announcements.start.getDate() + howMuch);
      announcements.end.setDate(announcements.end.getDate() + howMuch);
      return {...announcements};
    });
  }
```